# How do I add numbers in a different order?

Tags: c++

This is a simple question don't look for difficulties.

I have such a cycle

```
int arr[]{ 111, 222, 333 };
    
for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   test = 1000 * test + arr[i];    
}
std::cout << test;
```

it returns the result `111222333`

the question is how to make it output the result `333222111`
in short add numbers from the other side

you need to change this line to something else to add values in a different way

```
test = 1000 * test + arr[i];
```

I will update the question a little bit, that would be interesting, what if there is no array and you get the data in this form.

```
test = 1000 * test + X;
```

`X` is an unknown number and not an array

Comment: Well needless to say I love the accepted answer on the duplicate ;-)

Comment: If you're interested in c++20, you can use `std::ranges::views::reverse` as mentioned in the second dupe target.

Comment: updated the question )

Comment: An update shouldn't invalidate answers. You should instead ask a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
test = 1000 * test + arr[2 - i];
```

instead of the line.

To handle input other than arrays, you can use "delta" to keep track the place to insert new values.

```
int delta = 1;
for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    test += delta * X;
    delta *= 1000;
}
```

Comment: You were first to get the index correct. Oops. +1.

Comment: @Bathsheba Actually I prefer `arr[3 - 1 - i]` because we can use same `3` and therefore it is easy to replace this to constant value.

Comment: @MikeCAT: I can't resist putting in my preferred way `-->`.

Comment: updated the question and your example won't work now)

Comment: @buster added answer for the new question.

Comment: Yes, it's a better fit for me)

Answer (score 3):

You could do the loop from the end using reverse iterators:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int main() {
    int arr[]{ 111, 222, 333 };
    int test = 0;        
    for(auto it = std::rbegin(arr); it != std::rend(arr); ++it) {
        test = 1000 * test + *it;
    }
    std::cout << test;
}
```

Here's an alternative using [`std::accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) and a lambda:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <numeric>

int main() {
    int arr[]{ 111, 222, 333 };
    int test = std::accumulate(std::rbegin(arr), std::rend(arr), 0,
        [](const auto a, const auto b){
            return 1000 * a + b;
        }
    );
    std::cout << test;
}
```

Comment: Yup sensible. You'll get another vote if you can use a C++11 lamda in another answer?

Comment: @Bathsheba You mean as in using `std::accumulate` or `std::for-each` or something like that?

Comment: Absolutely, yes!

Comment: @Bathsheba Added :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can't reverse the elements in `arr`, perhaps the simplest way is to write

```
test = 1000 * test + arr[2 - i];
```

perhaps not hardcoding the 2. This is considerably simpler than running the loop the other way: `size_t` is `unsigned` so getting the stopping conditional correct takes some thought. Personally I use

```
for (size_t i = 3; i --> 0;) {
```

for this kind of thing. Note well the *slide operator* `-->`. It's not really an operator at all but it consists of the postfix `--` followed by the comparison. It's not to everyone's taste and some software houses ban its use.

Comment: thank, but I don't think it's worth writing this code `-->` :)

Comment: @buster: you don't like `for (size_t i = 3; i --> 0;) {`?

Comment: Another variant is `for (size_t i = 2; i <= 2; --i) {` but I don't like the repeat.

Comment: @Bathsheba it looks confusing to me, although it seems simple.

Comment: @buster: perhaps I've been doing this for too long now, but I find it natural, and no worse than function pointer declarations.

Comment: updated the question and your example won't work now)

Answer (score 1):

Iterate the loop from i=2 to 0 i.e for(size_t i = 2;  i  >= 0; i --)

Comment: This works if you use an `int`, but will not work for a `size_t` type.

Comment: updated the question and your example won't work now)